# How to get my normals functioning

Tags: normals, normal-map

[image]

Hello everyone!

So in the picture above you can see in the background one of my objects has a normal map that I am very happy with. I created another object and then applied the exact same material ... but the normals are not working ... they were both made the same way ( with solidifier and bevel mods ( which I applied ) ), I applied rotation and scale, I checked both of their UV maps, I looked through all of the object data, I double checked that they shared the right material, I went through all the display radio buttons, I recalculated the normals... and I am stumped as to why this is not working...

I feel like there must be some simple solution

THANK YOU!!

Comment: It would help if you posted screenshots of the node setup.

Comment: .. or even [shared your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)